# Firefox profile with proxy not working selenium webdriver python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, webdriver

proxy is not changing with this code.Is there any changes or better way ??

```
from selenium import webdriver

_drivPath = r"C:\Users\abc\Desktop\geckodriver.exe"

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http", "96.42.212.235")
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", 8080)
profile.update_preferences()

_driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=_drivPath, 
firefox_profile=profile)
_driver.get("https://whatismyipaddress.com")
```

Comment: So to clarify, `whatismyipaddress` gives you your real IP and you want to be using 96.42.212.235?

Comment: Yes, Thats right after using the proxy in 'whatismyipaddress' still shows the real ip. How will i know if the proxy is working right ? is there a way to log it somewhere or get the webdriver proxy or anything solution?